# Looping through array and setting visible property of instances - ActionScript3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, variables

I have variable names stored in an array, and I want to loop through array and set the visible property of that instance to false. However, I'm getting error;

> Error #1056: Cannot create property visible on String.

Here is my code:

```
package  {
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class touch extends MovieClip
    {
        public function touch()
        {
            var menuitems:Array = new Array("menu_One", "menu_Two", "menu_Three", "menu_Three", "menu_Four", "menu_Five");//array with instance names
            for(var i:int=0;i<6;i++){
                var tempName = menuitems[i];
                bsF_txt.text = tempName;
                trace(tempName);
                tempName.visible = false;
                //menu_One.visible = false;
            }

         }
      }
}
```

Is. what  I'm trying to do possible in AS3?

Comment: The `String` Object in As3 does not have a visible parameter.  There is no .visible for `String` which is causing your error. What are you trying to accomplish? It would work if you had say movieclips instead of a string... I just noticed your comment that those strings are instance names so I added an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code (I just noticed you said those are instance names...)

```
package  { 
import flash.events.TouchEvent; 
import flash.ui.Multitouch; 
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode; 
import flash.display.MovieClip; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 

public class touch extends MovieClip 
{ 
    public function touch() 
    { 
        var menuitems:Array = new Array("menu_One", "menu_Two", "menu_Three", "menu_Three", "menu_Four", "menu_Five");//array with instance names 
        for(var i:int=0;i<6;i++){ 
            var tempName = menuitems[i]; 
            bsF_txt.text = tempName; 
            trace(tempName); 
            getChildByName(tempName).visible = false; 
            //menu_One.visible = false; 
        } 

     } 
  } 
}
```

The main change is that you need to tell flash that the string in your array is an instance name.  So use `getChildByName` assuming they are added to to the stage.

The reason your current code is failing is because you are trying to access the visible property on a String, but `String` does not have a `visible` property.  But the actually instance of that string name might.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I was thinking the compiler would automatically try and find the instance for the given string.

Answer (score 2):

First yes it is possible!

The problem is your looping through an array of strings, not variables or anything that references a DisplayObject (maybe a MovieClip in your case?)

Assuming those strings are either instance names of MovieClips that are on your stage or vars that are referencing them you could try something like this:

```
public function touch()
    {
        var menuitems:Array = new Array(menu_One, menu_Two, menu_Three, menu_Three, "menu_Four", menu_Five);//if this gives you an error please paste some more code because these are not instance names or vars
        for(var i:int=0; i<menuitems.length ;i++){ //you don't need to explicitly use 6 here you can check the menuitems arrays length 
            var tempName = menuitems[i]; //note, this is not needed
            bsF_txt.text = tempName.name; //I think you're looking for this?
            trace(tempName);
            tempName.visible = false;
            //menu_One.visible = false;
        }

     }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was using the 'tempName' to check if the menu items were actually being read, hence the trace a line later. Thanks this works fine, as well as the M. Laing's solution.

Comment: @user1005253 Cool. In this case you can just do all your actions on menuitems[i]